# SQL: Query Entire Schema for Specific Value and Return Table Names

Tags: sql, database, vba

more adventures of my having to embed SQL in VBA code to get info from the company's database... Our database has probably a couple thousand database tables, so if you are looking for something in-particular, you have to do a lot of poking around (especially if the name of the table isn't as intuitive as something like "ITEMS").

I had a general idea of what the column header I was looking for was called, and came across this code to find it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASE'
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%MFGR%';
```

This returned the names of all the tables with columns containing %MFGR%... Found the table I needed pretty quick.... much quicker than arbitrarily importing tables that look like they might be it.

Anyway, what would be better is to have a query that returned the names of all the tables containing a certain value in any column. Usually I have no clue what the column is named, but know what one of the values is. I just want to know what tables contain it so I can look at them.

This kept coming up as a result: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

Sounds like it will probably work, but is there a simpler way? I haven't tried putting it into VBA code yet.

EDIT: Looking at the code, it looks like it involves manipulating the database (creating procedures, creating tables, etc.) which I don't have the access to do. Anyway to do this just as a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pleas, use below query for output, where database is name of database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.name 
FROM   database.sys.columns C 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN database.sys.tables T 
                    ON T.object_id = C.object_id 
WHERE  C.name LIKE '%name%'
```

Comment: Ok, so disregard my previous comment since I was an idiot who wasn't even pulling the correct variable that I assigned the SQL query to. But still having issues. Using the code above and replacing 'database' with 'QSF', I get an ODBC error. 'Doing 'LOCAL.QSF' I get an SQL error.

Comment: Any other suggestions?